# how to divide number into parts by 3

Tags: ios, string, uilabel

I have a simple `UILabel`, string and variable `x` (double).
I output it

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%15.10g", x];
[newlabel setText:string];
```

for example I have `x = 555444333`, so in label there is a `" 55544433 "` result (obv).

I need to output it like `" 555 444 333 "` (like in a calculator), are there some simple methods to do that?

Comment: What type is `x`?  It looks like it should be `double` but then you state its value as `555444333` which is an integer.

Comment: Yep, it's double, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NSNumberFormatter setting up the groupingSeparator as a string containing a single space and the groupingSize = 3:

```
int x = 35464546;//the value of your int x
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@" "];
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x];
[newlabel setText:string];
```

I used an int in the example as although you said x is a double then you described it as an int 555444333. If you need to use a double change the code accordingly: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(double) yourDoubleValue]

Comment: Thank's a lot! That's exatly what I need! Works perfectly. Yep, you are right, just changed to numberWithDouble. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing that e.g. by creating a `NSNumberFormatter` - which could be an "easy" solution.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"### ### ###"];
NSString *formattedNumberString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@55544433];
```

the `NSNumberFormatter` is accepting a `NSNumber` so put wrap numeric value into an `NSNumber` like `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:yourInteger]` and replace the content @55544433 with that `NSNumber`